# View class doesn't seem to have FILL_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT properties

Tags: android

GridView doesn't have a LayoutParams() function 
and View doesn't have a View.WRAP_CONTENT.
What is wrong with my setup ?

Answer (score 1):

No class in Android has "a `LayoutParams()` function", as Java does not have functions, and Java methods usually start with a lowercase letter.

`GridView` has [a `getLayoutParams()` method, inherited from `View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams%28%29).

[`FILL_PARENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT) and [`WRAP_CONTENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#WRAP_CONTENT) are public static data members on `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, the base class for all `LayoutParams` classes used in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Why should there be a `View.WRAP_CONTENT`? There is a constant `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`.

Answer (score 0):

`LayoutParams` is the name of a class, where most `Layout` classes have special implementations of. The base class is defined in `ViewGroup`. See the JavaDoc to see what classes have derived implementations.

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

WRAP_CONTENT is defined in the `ViewGroup` class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#WRAP_CONTENT

Answer (score 0):

It uses LayoutParams from the layout parent. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470318/setting-parameter-of-layout-of-android-programmatically)

If you want to place a button inside a LinearLayout, you must do this.

```
button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```