# How can I programmatically include layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, parameters, include, xamarin.android

I'm looking for a way to include a layout programmatically instead of using the XML tag  `include` like in my example:

```
  <include layout="@layout/message"  
           android:layout_width="match_parent" 
           android:layout_height="match_parent" 
           android:layout_weight="0.75"/>
```

Need to change this parameter "**layout="@layout/message**" programmatically, please.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: As far as I understand from your question, you are looking a way to change paramaters of your layout programatically, so here is the link : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501831/add-layout-with-parameters-programmatically-android) and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470318/setting-parameter-of-layout-of-android-programmatically).

Comment: You can't really do it like that. What you can do is inflate the layout in-code and add the inflated view to your parent layout. Or you can use Fragments.

Comment: OK. So if you want to change the "layout" paramater, kcoppock's answer is suitable.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Use a `ViewStub` instead of `include`:

```
<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/layout_stub"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/message_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.75" />
```

Then in code, get a reference to the stub, set its layout resource, and inflate it:

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.layout_stub);
stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.whatever_layout_you_want);
View inflated = stub.inflate();
```

Comment: @kcoppock thanks it's ok but how i call the TextView in my layout because with this code  TextView  close1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.close1);   i have error

Comment: @kcoppock and how i can change view after button click ( i have 4 view )

Comment: No need to keep the inflated view in a separate variable, the layout is added to the original one so the components can de retrieved using findViewById as usual, so just call stub.inflate();

Comment: Unless you immediately want to do something with the inflated result.

Comment: any another idea to make ViewStub invisible/visible programmatically..??

Comment: Very useful tool. Made my life much easier and my code way simpler.

Comment: i want to load multiple layouts in a sequence,once i load the first layout when i go to load the second layout i get stub as null, isnt the layout being loaded within the Viewstub so shouldnt i be able to access the parent viewstub?

Comment: @kcoppock i got `The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first` error, can you help me?

Comment: @UmangKothari `inflated.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` & `inflated.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` works fine for me...

Comment: How to initiate a view in included(stub) layout?  - when try to initiate as normal process - null pointer exception ? any help

Comment: Exactly the thing which I was looking for

Answer (score 6):

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.text_post);
        stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.profile_header);
        View inflated = stub.inflate();
```

Comment: how will you use the views inside profile_header.xml ?

Answer (score 3):

In Mono.Droid / Xamarin this worked for me:

```
ViewStub stub = FindViewById<ViewStub>(Resource.Id.layout_stub);
stub.LayoutResource = Resource.Layout.whatever_layout_you_want;
stub.Inflate();
```

Answer (score 1):

**ViewStub Kotlin Implementation**

Inside your **onCreate** function:

```
val viewStub: ViewStub? = binding?.viewStub
viewStub?.layoutResource = R.layout.your_layout

if (viewStub?.parent != null) {
    viewStub.inflate()
}
```

*Don't forget to comment for any inquiries*