# Replace `layout` of an <include/> tag programmatically for Android

Tags: android, xml

I want to change the `layout` of my `<include/>` tag dynamically/programmatically.

I have a main `layout` that I want to re-use but the contents should change dynamically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        layout="REPLACE_THIS" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Above is the xml that I am using, I am assuming that you will need to find the id of the include and then change it programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999601/how-can-i-programmatically-include-layout-in-android), it may contain your solution.

Comment: I've found this other question and it has been answered http://stackoverflow.com/a/18999694/788205

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer a couple of months ago. You just need to use a ViewStub and inflate the appropriate one.

Comment: Please care to provide solution rather just winding up like this.

Comment: Can you please add the solution?

Answer (score 12):

Just change the code in the respective java file (e.g. *MainActivity.java*):

```
// Retrieve layout:
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_container); 

// Instantiate & use inflater:
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

// Clear & set new views:
mainLayout.removeAllViews();
mainLayout.addView(layout);
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this manner

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id. main_container); 
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, mainLayout, true);
mainLayout.removeAllView();
mainLayout.addView(layout);
```

Before adding the view you have to remove all the views first and then inflate the layout in it as shown above

Answer (score 0):

Too late for response but after some exhausting time I figure out a simple way to re-use xml file inside a parent layout. Just add the **#include** tag in your xml then don't forget to removeallviews inside the java class. Then it works. Follow the procedures above but again and again don't forget to add include tag in your parent xml file. Otherwise it won't work