# Change include tag layout programmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm doing an Android project and I'm trying to figure out how to be dynamic in layouts.

So I have layout files `complex_card.xml` and `simple_card.xml`, each containing a `ConstraintLayout` tag with some other layout elements inside. `complex_card` takes more space than `simple_card` so I will use `complex_card` whenever I have a lot of space and can switch back to using `simple_card` when I don't have space.

In `activity_main.xml`, I've use both of the layouts via `<include layout="R.layout.complex_card"/>` tags. However, in real time, I want to be able to change that to `<include layout="R.layout.simple_card"/>`. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically include layout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999601/how-can-i-programmatically-include-layout-in-android)

Comment: No that won't be good because I want to be able to switch layouts from simple_card to complex_card multiple times but with ViewStub, you can inflate the layout only once.

Comment: Consider using [addView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#addview) / [removeView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#removeview) to replace your views. Maybe [ViewFlipper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper) will suit better.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a work around to this. `simple_card` is a light weight version of `complex_card` which means I can use `view.visibility = View.GONE` and `view.visibility = View.VISIBLE` to hide certain layouts in `complex_card` which looks exactly like `simple_card`.

However, the original problem isn't solved if there are 2 completely different layout files.