# Change layout in 'Include' programmatically using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am writing a simple game and I'm wanting the main screen to have a choice of 3 layouts, for 2 handed, right handed or left handed.

I have an `include` for the controls. However I'm struggling to get the `layout` to change programatically. Been searching since last night but cannot find a way to do it, is it even possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GamePlay">
 <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        layout="@layout/hand_two" <!-- this is what needs to change depending on settings -->
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/handLayout"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: No, that's not directly possible. I would suggest visibility change inside your included layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically include layout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999601/how-can-i-programmatically-include-layout-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **animusmind**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999601/how-can-i-programmatically-include-layout-in-android):
Use a ViewStub instead of include:

```
<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/layout_stub"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/message_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.75" />
```

Then in code, get a reference to the stub, set its layout resource, and inflate it:

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.layout_stub);
stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.whatever_layout_you_want);
View inflated = stub.inflate();
```

Answer collected from **kcoppock**

Comment: not ideal having to use a stub as I cannot see it in the layout, but have gone this route. The above is in Java though, of which I know none. I think I have it working though, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple views which you would like to load them on demand programatically, ViewStub is one of the solution

please visit like link [viewStub for multiple view](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-dynamically-load-view-with-viewstub/)