# Include layout in XML depends on condition

Tags: android, xml, layout, data-binding, include

I have parent layout with databinding. I want to add child layout depends on logic.
I expected to need similar code:

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_id"
        layout="@{model.isOk ? @layout/layout_container_1 : @layout/layout_container_2}"
        app:model="@{model}" />
```

But I get error:

```
android.databinding.tool.processing.ScopedException: [databinding] {"msg":"included value (@{model.isOk ? @layout/layout_container_1 : @layout/layout_container_2}) must start with @layout/.","file":"x.xml","pos":[]}
```

Is it possible to include child layout dynamically through "if-else" condition? If yes what is the best way? Any samples are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible with the current implementation of `<include>` tag. By "implementation" I mean how it is actually used by the SDK.

`<include>` tag is parsed in the process of layout inflation which means `layout` attribute of `<include>` tag must have a layout resource ID defined **before** any of your code logic can be executed. While data-binding is what you can use after a layout was successfully inflated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to include child layout dynamically through "if-else" condition?

So far, this is not possible, because the `layout` attribute must point to a certain layout before the data-binding works:

**(Data Binding)** As its name implies, it binds data to a layout, so there must be a layout first, in order to bind data to it.

In other words, the `layout="@{model.isOk ? @layout/layout_container_1 : @layout/layout_container_2}"` doesn't work because there should be an existing layout before examining `model.isOk`, and also the `layout` attribute expects a layout resource after the `@` symbol.

So, [we need to do that programmatically instead of the XML layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999601/how-can-i-programmatically-include-layout-in-android). And this an be done by replacing the `<include>` with [`ViewStub`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub) which is a sort of deferring layout inflation to be done in the activity.

So before inflating the `ViewStub` layout, you can have a chance to check whether the `model.isOk` in the activity before deciding which layout can be inflated on the `ViewStub`.

And hence based on the `model.isOk` value, we can set the layout with `binding.myLayoutStub.myViewStub?.layoutResource = R.layout.layout_container_1`

Eventually we can inflate the new `ViewStub` layout using `binding.myLayoutStub.myViewStub?.inflate()` method.

Using the `ViewStub`, will make you have a couple of binding object, one for the activity (or fragment), and the other for the inflated layout of the `ViewStub`.

**Here is an example like yours:**

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="model"
            type="com.example.android.databindingexample.ActivityViewModel" />

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/layout_stub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

And we've `layout_container_1` & `layout_container_2` that only differ in the the textview value:

layout_container_1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/purple_200">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Layout 1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

ViewModel:

```
class ActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var isOk = true
}
```

Then decide which layout in the activity based on the `model.isOk` whenever you inflate the ViewStub:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    // This is of Any type as it will be casted later to the proper DataBinding generated class when the ViewStub layout inflated
    private lateinit var stubBinding: Any

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        val model = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ActivityViewModel::class.java)

        binding.model = model

        // Listener to ViewStub inflation so that we can change its layout
        binding.layoutStub.setOnInflateListener { _, inflated ->
            stubBinding =
                (if (model.isOk) DataBindingUtil.bind<LayoutContainer1Binding>(
                    inflated
                )
                else DataBindingUtil.bind<LayoutContainer2Binding>(
                    inflated
                ))!!
            
            // Changing the text of the inflated layout in the ViewStub using the ViewStubBinding
            if (model.isOk)
                (stubBinding as (LayoutContainer1Binding)).textview.text = "This is Layout container 1"
            else
                (stubBinding as (LayoutContainer2Binding)).textview.text = "This is Layout container 2"
        }


        // Inflating the ViewStub
        if (!binding.layoutStub.isInflated) {
            binding.layoutStub.viewStub?.layoutResource = if (model.isOk)
                R.layout.layout_container_1 else R.layout.layout_container_2

            binding.layoutStub.viewStub?.inflate()
        }

    }

}
```

Preview:

[image]